# Prompt UAC when required for read file from c#

Tags: c#, uac

when I read file with binary reader:

```
using (FileStream FilStr = new FileStream(MainPreferenceModel.Instance.PrintHeader.CompanyLogoFilePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (BinaryReader BinRed = new BinaryReader(FilStr))
    {
        HeaderFooterReportModel.Logo = BinRed.ReadBytes((int)BinRed.BaseStream.Length);
        BinRed.Close();
    }
    FilStr.Close();
}
```

It is OK, but when opening file e.g. *C:\logo.jpg* it throw exception.
Is posible to Get UAC prompt only for reading this file? -user use FileOpenDialog to get path.

I found way how to run program as Admin on startup, but is there way how to get access to file on path like this? I can copy that file to some other path via run command as admin, but its not solution for this.

Thanks for reply

Comment: C:\ is considered as system, do you really need to store your file here?

Comment: I recall that the OpenFileDialog class has an OpenFile() method -- I seem to remember that .Net would in some cases allow this method to work as it knew the filename came from a user supplied input. Don't recall the details, and don't know if it would work in your case. It looks like you intended to refer to OpenFileDialog in your answer, so presumably you can try this very easily.

Comment: I dont need it, but users sometimes do and application could open this file if possible.

Comment: Gary: your idea works sometime. I really can open file with calling OpenFile() method. With jpg files it works fine, but when I try open serialize file which is is signed by SHA1, Verification fails. When I open the same file from D:\ it succeed. So it probably add some extra information when opening from C:\. Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  using (FileStream FilStr = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
```

The real problem here is that you are not specific enough about the access you want to the file.  The way you wrote it, you leave it up to FileStream to select a file access.  And it will pick FileAccess.ReadWrite.  You are not going to get that on the C:\ directory, it is protected for write access without UAC elevation.  And you don't need it, you are only reading from the file.

Fix:

```
  using (FileStream FilStr = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But sometime it fails. With jpg files it works fine, but when I try open serialize file which is is signed by SHA1, Verification fails. When I open the same file from D:\ it succeed. So it probably add some extra information when opening from C:\. Any Idea what happens and how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Answer (score 1):

Elevation is performed at process startup only. So there is no way to elevate during the life of a process. You have to decide once and for all at startup.

What applications typically do is to start new processes to perform specific tasks that require elevation. You can start a new instance of the application passing command line arguments and using the `runas` verb to request elevation. Or you can use an elevated out-of-process COM server to do the work. The former is quicker to set up, but the latter is a cleaner solution.

Comment: I would be interested in a small elaboration or link to resources why OOP COM is a cleaner solution, vs. a separate process.

Comment: @vcsjones Because you can program against COM just like any other object. Pass parameters, get values back, block until the function returns. That's messy with Process.Start.

Comment: Thanks, I know this, but I cant believe it hasnt better solution. What write Hans works sometimes... When file is signed via SHA1 and opening with FileAccess.Read, it add some extra information... so verification of sign fails.

Comment: Well, if you know this, why did you ask the question. You asked *Is possible to Get UAC prompt only for reading this file?*

Answer (score 0):

You have to **create/modify your application manifest** like in this Microsoft example (for an assembly called IsUserAdmin.exe):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="X86"
     name="IsUserAdmin"
     type="win32"/> 
  <description>Description of your application</description> 
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

**More info** here:
**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx**

Comment: I know this option, but that require rights on whole application. I need application run with normal rights and when it is required get access to file with some extra restriction. I know that isnt possible get higher rights for app when its runnig. But is possible to claim access to these file? Thanks

Comment: Well you can create a separate application used only for file manipulation with compiled elevated privilages demand and interact with your base one. The only other option I know is the one presented in the answer by David Heffernan. That's the way you should probably go.